# How make a simple rest-framework example?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a hello world in `Django` and `rest-framework`, but when acess the url: `http://localhost:4444/products` to get all products the terminal is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 45, in list
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 110, in get_serializer
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
[06/Dec/2019 11:49:35] "GET /products HTTP/1.1" 500 17530
```

I use Django, but i dont know how start a project from 0. Here is my code:

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductListSerializer


class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    lookup_field = 'pk'
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductListSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path


from . import views
import product.views as v

product_detail = v.ProductViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve',
                                           'delete': 'destroy',
                                           'patch': 'partial_update'})

product_list = v.ProductViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list'})

urlpatterns = [
    path('products/<int:pk>', product_detail),
    path('products', product_list),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'product'
        index_together = [
            ['title'],
        ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return '(Product)%s' % self.title
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Product

class ProductListSerializer():

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title']
```

I already make the migrations and migrate. I have no data in my DB, but the response of my request url it had to be a response with 0 items. I'm doing something wrong or forgetting something important?

Comment: are you added `path('', include('NameOfYourApp.urls'))` in your general app?

Comment: ```from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('product.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I think the problem is how i using the serializer, but i have no clue

Comment: maybe it could be this :`fields = ['title']`
base on doc https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example

Comment: same error, i will change in the question

Comment: Their is no need to do this " fields = ['title'] ", you can pass tuple too. Why dont you try to pass "serializers.ModelSerializer" inside your serializers class.

Comment: try this `class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`

Comment: I forget to add this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the serializer class

try this

```
from .models import Product
from rest_framework import serializers
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```